# How to build a perpendicular in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I need to build a perpendicular (line at an angle of 90 degrees to the original line) across the mid point of a straight line.

`line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );`

```
geometry.vertices.push(   
  new THREE.Vector3( 100, 200, 0 ),  
  new THREE.Vector3( 300, 500, 0 )  );
```

In the manual I was not found information about it.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Line

Thank you!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) respectively [Non-English Question Policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: Better to ask it here: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/three.js

Answer (score 2):

You can find the normal of a line by subtracting its start point from its end point (thus you'll get its direction), then rotate the resulted vector at 90 degrees (Math.PI * 0.5), then normalize it, and this is it, you've got the normal.

In the code snippet, the line itself is blueish (aqua), its normal is red.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
grid.rotation.x = -Math.PI * 0.5;
scene.add(grid);

var lineVertices = [
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 2),
  new THREE.Vector3(3, 5)
];

var lineGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(lineVertices);
var lineMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ffff});
var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeom, lineMat);
scene.add(line);

var midPoint = new THREE.Vector3()
  .subVectors(lineVertices[1], lineVertices[0])
  .multiplyScalar(0.5)
  .add(lineVertices[0]);
  
var normal = new THREE.Vector3()
  .subVectors(lineVertices[1], lineVertices[0])
  .applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), Math.PI * 0.5)
  .normalize();
  
  
var normalVertices = [
  normal.clone().setLength(2).add(midPoint),
  normal.clone().negate().setLength(2).add(midPoint)
];

var normalGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(normalVertices);
var normalMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000 });
var normal = new THREE.Line(normalGeom, normalMat);
scene.add(normal);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{renderer.render(scene, camera)});
```

```css
body {
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is two-D; Three is Three-D.